# I have a Harbor Breeze ceiling fan and lights. I can't find bulbs that work

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling

I have a 52 inch/132 cm edenton, Model#L2AP, Item #0154637.

It says use 4 40 Watt A candelabra base bulbs. I could only find A15 and lights are not working. Can anyone please help me? Do l need specific bulbs? I never had issues like this with anything in my life? Thanks SO much! Georgia

Answer (score 1):

**Candelabra** is a type of lamp base (the screwey thing at the bottom).  It is the second most common after Edison E27. They are widely supported and are readily available in LED at prices comparable to E27 (unlike less common sizes, where they come at a premium).

You shouldn't have any trouble finding such bulbs at places that sell Harbor Breeze fans.  If that fails, try Ikea.